# Ancestor binding of Tag Dependency Property fails with Property not found

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

I’m building a MEF based module loading framework … the basic layout is that the main MEF application loads modules and data binds to various exported object including the module’s Ribbon and the modules main view (as a UserControl).

In the modules the Ribbon is defined in one XAML file as a ResourceDictionary and the main view (the module’s window content) is defined in a separate XAML file as a UserControl.

The MEF Framework App’s main window XAML binds the module’s usercontrol and ribbon.  With the ribbon it also links the Ribbon’s Tag dependency property to the UserControl.  This way the actual Module Ribbon can access the UserControl (for things like determining what elements are selected in a grid).

This all works fine … the Tag is properly associated with the UserControl.  The problem I run into is in the module’s Ribbon.  I try to bind to subelements in the UserControl and the binding fails.  Here is an example of the module’s ribbon binding that is failing:

```
<ribbon:RibbonButton
   Command=”blah”
   Label={“Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ribbon:Ribbon},
   Path=Tag.Username.Text}”/>
```

As I mentioned Tag is properly resolved to the module’s UserControl … but I then get a binding error on Username (property not found).

Here is how I bind the Tag property in the MEF Framework App’s main window:

```
<ribbon:Ribbon x:Name=”Ribbon”
   DataContext=”blah”,
   Tag=”{Binding ElementName=RibbonWindow,              
   Path=DataContext.ModuleList.CurrentItem.View}”>
```

BTW I’m a little hamstrung in the fact that I can’t use Prism …

Comment: Sounds like you might need to append DataContext to View. Try using **Snoop** to figure out what the datacontext of that is in runtime.

Comment: Erode - Good thought ... Adding DataContext gave me access to the Module's ViewModel. Which is helpful, but wont allow me to access any of the objects in the View. I'll work on getting Snoop ... but getting new tools installed around here can sometimes take some time.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) is an open source tool, it shouldn't be any problem to acquire.

Comment: snoop looks cool ... and the problem isnt the cost ... my company requires security reviews of all new tools we bring in.  Those security reviews take time.  Do you have any other thoughts on how to access the View?

Comment: Oh, sorry to assume.  It didn't occur to me at first but it seems as though you're binding to a UIElement's text property, which I don't believe would work anyway.  I think ElementName binding source object must be used for binding to controls in the XAML, but the NameScope is likely going to prohibit this. Why not bind directly to the property which Username is bound to?

Comment: Very fair ... In this particular case I could do that.  But (and I didnt mention this above) I was also trying to solve the problem for a DataGrid where I needed the SelectedItems (emphasis on plural) where that approach would not work.

Comment: Unfortunately that was my last good idea. If you got desperate you could provide an instance of the View on the ViewModel you were able to bind to with my previous suggestion.  Not sure if Prism passes in the View when loading or attaching the ViewModel but it might work.